# Obtaining total and free used space via Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I discover just today that [`DriveApp#getStorageUsed()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getStorageUsed%28%29) is referring ONLY to Google Drive.

I didn't expect this behaviour because `getStorageLimit` is intended as global. in fact, says 15 GB for my free account.

I don't understand how to get the amout of used storage OR totally OR divided by services.

My problem is that I've a lot of photos on Google Photos and these are not summed as storage space used.

Is there a way to get OR the sum of used space OR used space by service (via single api call or via  a set of api calls) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is no longer valid.

<s>`getStorageUsed` and `getStorageLimit` both give the numbers for your "Google Drive Storage" as mentioned in the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getStorageUsed%28%29) you've refered. This storage is not just for Google Drive though, it is shared across Drive, Gmail (and its attachments) and Google Photos as well. Two things to note here:</s>

<s>1. At Google Photos - If you chose "High Quality" when uploading instead of "Original", then you get unlimited storage space. So this will not get counted in your StorageUsed. [Reference](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791). This might be the reason why you think `getStorageUsed` is returning only for Drive even when you have a lot of photos in Google Photos.</s>

<s>2. At Google Drive - Anything you’ve created with Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides doesn’t count toward your storage limit. You get almost unlimited storage for them.</s>

<s>Hope that solves your doubt.</s>

Comment: No, I asked how to get email quota, google photo quota (thanks for the workaround) etc ...  If I've 2 GB of Email and 13 GB on Drive, I've exausted my free space .. but I cannot detect with this API only

Comment: getStorageUsed() Is returning only drive storage used and _not_ gmail.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Apps Script native `DriveApp` doesn't have the ability to check other services, but if the "Advanced Service" Drive (which uses v2 of the Drive REST API) is [enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), then the quotas of Drive, Photos, and Gmail can be queried simply, using the [`About`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about) collection:

```
// Read Drive quotas.
function getAbout() {
  var about = Drive.About.get();
  about.quotaBytesByService.forEach(function (s) {console.log(s)});
}
```

Which logs:

```
{"bytesUsed":"1010101010","serviceName":"DRIVE"}
{"bytesUsed":"9876543210","serviceName":"PHOTOS"}
{"bytesUsed":"1234567890","serviceName":"GMAIL"}
```

There are additional properties of the `About` collection that may be of interest, such as `quotaBytesTotal` and `quotaBytesUsed`. The Script Editor's autocomplete and the API reference linked above will no doubt be helpful.